# Laravel - Error messages not translating to actual error message, start with "validation."

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, localization

I am having issues trying to get form validation working in Laravel which is odd because it usually just works.

In my user model I have created rules for the validation:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'firstname'=>'required|min:2|alpha',
    'lastname'=>'required|min:2|alpha',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:8,12|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:8,12',
    'telephone'=>'required|between:10,12',
    'admin'=>'integer'
);
```

In my user controller I define actions only if the validation passes, if not the user is redirected back with errors:

```
public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->telephone = Input::get('telephone');
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('users/signin')
            ->with('message', 'Thank you for creating a new account. Please sign in.');
    }

    return Redirect::to('users/create-account')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

The following errors have occurred:

In the view i display the errors if they exist:

```
@if($errors->has())
    <div id="form-errors">
    <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div><!-- end form-errors -->
@endif
```

The problem that I have is that the output of this when submitting an empty form is:

```
validation.required
validation.required
validation.required
validation.required
validation.required
validation.required
```

Instead of:

```
The firstname field is required.
The lastname field is required.
The email field is required.
The password field is required.
The password confirmation field is required.
The telephone field is required.
```

If anyone could suggest why this is happening or what I am missing then this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Having same issue in Laravel 5 and don't know why...

Comment: Me too! In Laravel 5, but only with certain environments / servers

Comment: @Lloople Quite sad, actually put me off Laravel... Not bad because I am learning more Javascript now :) If you found an answer please post it though?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity My problem was I overwrote the default settings with Config::set('app', $my_config_array) and because of that I lose the app.language value.

Answer (score 10):

If it has worked for you before then you should check if you have messages defined in the `app\lang\en\validation.php` or by chance you have changed the **locale** of the app and have not defined the messages for it. There are many possibilities.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am using the default error messages which are indeed defined in the validation.php file. Really odd, everything seems to be 100% correct but the validation is not translating the errors into messages?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, and the problem to me was that I've accidentally deleted
resources/lang/en/validation.php

Answer (score 4):

I had that issue.
Check the `lang` directory, it should be placed in the `resource` directory.

I dragged lang directory to another directory, and then I got the same validation response as you. The fix was just to move it back to resource directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I had set both my locale and backup locale to a locale that had no validation file in app.php. Try setting your backup locale to en or one that you are sure exists.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem check your `lang` directory exits or not under `/resources` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, here is the solution for this problem

**Check whether `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file exists or not**

or

**Change your locale and fallback_locale to 'en' in config\app.php**

```
'locale' => 'en',
...
...
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
...
```

then run, `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

File **`project\lang\en\validation.php`** is *missing* in **`project\resources\lang\en\validation.php`**.

**SIMPLE**: `lang` folder it not exists in `resources\lang`. Just copy paste **lang** folder in **resources**.

**How I figure it out?**
I install a new laravel app with breez Vue Inertia and it worked fine with errors messages, then I compare my current project structure and do some research and finally got the solution.

Just copy whole folder from `project\lang` and paste in `project\resources\lang`. If there is no lang folder in resources then simply create it and paste copied files. And its worked! This error mostly happened when you create simple ***Laravel project*** and later install Vue etc. and during installation/configuration the `lang` folder may skip accidentally in `resources/lang`.

If you have no `validation.php` file, then simply goto github laravel/laravel and copy that file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file at

```
resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

And copy content from this url
[PHPClasses](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/94712.html)

Comment: It's still not understandable why would he do this, there's no enough information

Comment: Because these steps fixed my problem and now it's showing the actual error rather validation.required, it's nothing but only two steps, one create a file named validation.php at the specified location and two, copy content from the PHPClasses

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

I replaced the resources folder with my older one where there was no `lang/en/validation.php` and that was the cause, you just have to add the file!!